# Java -version and compiling is slow

Tags: java, centos, javac

I am running CentOS release 6.6 (Final) and have openjdk 1.8.0_31 installed.  If I run "java -version" or "javac -version" or compile a simple program, it takes over 30 seconds to return.  Is anyone aware of issues some as this in the CentOS environment?  I found [gcc or javac slow at first startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799154/gcc-or-javac-slow-at-first-startup), but subsequent invocations of javac are still slow.

Comment: I'd use Oracle's JDK.

Comment: @Jared I absolutely agree with you

Comment: I have experienced slowness with OpenJDK on Ubuntu, so I understand his problem.